# Calculating minimum or maximum by index in list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

```
list_of_elements = [1255, 1256, 1257, 1258, 1259]
print(components[1255],components[1256],components[1257],components[1258],components[1259])
```

Output of the print is:

```
[481, 498, 5142, 5157] [481, 497, 5192, 5199] [481, 498, 5219, 5238] [481, 484, 5239, 5242] [481, 487, 5269, 5271)]
```

What I want to do is to take the smallest number of the first index(0), the biggest of the second, smallest of the third and biggest of the fourth so i'll end up with in this case:

```
[481,498,5142,5271]
```

So, again, basically I'll be given a list of elements (in this case it's `list_of_elements`, might have 0 values up to unknown), then I have to input the elements of that list as keys in a dictionary `components` and do the steps explained above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way you can structure your logic via a dispatcher dictionary and a couple of list comprehensions:

```
list_of_elements = [1255, 1256, 1257, 1258, 1259]

# extract data via list comprehension
L = [components[i] for i in list_of_elements]

# defined explicitly for demonstration
L = [[481, 498, 5142, 5157], [481, 497, 5192, 5199],
     [481, 498, 5219, 5238], [481, 484, 5239, 5242],
     [481, 487, 5269, 5271]]

from operator import itemgetter

# define dispatcher dictionary
funcs = {0: min, 1: max}

# apply via list comprehension
res = [funcs[i%2](map(itemgetter(i), L)) for i in range(len(L[0]))]

print(res)

[481, 498, 5142, 5271]
```

**Explanation**

- `i%2` returns either 0 or 1 depending on whether your index is even or odd.
- `funcs[i%2]` returns  either `min` or `max` as defined in the `funcs` dictionary.
- `map(itemgetter(i), L)` returns an iterator over the `i`th element of each list within `L`.
- Applying `funcs[i%2]` on this iterator returns either the minimum or maximum.

Comment: Works nicely can you explain the `res` step tho i didn't understand how the dispatcher dictionary was applied there.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses a ternary statement and `enumerate` + `zip` within a list comprehension:

```
L = [[481, 498, 5142, 5157], [481, 497, 5192, 5199],
     [481, 498, 5219, 5238], [481, 484, 5239, 5242],
     [481, 487, 5269, 5271]]

res = [(min if not i%2 else max)(j) for i, j in enumerate(zip(*L))]

print(res)

[481, 498, 5142, 5271]
```